# Blazor+Electron.NET app crashes on startup

Tags: asp.net-core, electron, electron.net

I've built a Blazor server app hosted in Electron.NET and it works fine when I run it in the browser. After building it as a Windows executable it crashes during startup with the following error.

[image: Screenshot of the crash]

Is there a way to dig out more details about the crash? The displayed error message doesn't help me much

I'm running .NET Core 3.1 and ElectronNET.API version 7.30.2

Answer (score 0):

Please try again with the latest Electron.NET version 8.31.1.

One tutorial from the community:
https://youtu.be/FsRoJ0_VtDw